# Unable to install ubuntu snap in 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I'm unable to install snap in Ubuntu 16.04, instead, I get the error shown below:

```
dheer@dheer-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo snap install notes  
[sudo] password for dheer:  *********

error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Fetch and check assertions for snap "ubuntu-core" (423) (Get https://assertions.ubuntu.com/v1/assertions/snap-revision/7sS9MbzjeZ87E4IVq3ByrAO8t1YqriNlaX4r7eT5AHYZjzRCa7twTmWU53e6falH: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers))
dheer@dheer-Inspiron-3558:~$
```

Please help?

Comment: $ sudo snap install hello-world           
error: cannot install "hello-world": Get https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/api/v1/snaps/details/ubuntu-core?channel=stable&confinement=strict: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557968/net-http-request-canceled-client-timeout-exceeded-while-awaiting-headers-why

Comment: it sounds like your internet is broken

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a status code of 423 which indicates the content you are trying to access is locked. This indicates that snap "ubuntu-core" may be in the process of being modified at the time of your attempt to access it. In my case attempts to access assertions.ubuntu.com/v1/assertions/snap-revision lead to a 403 error (Forbidden) as I don't have access.